# Kotlinのreturn文について

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

そこで入力されたUserIDのdocumentが存在すればエラーを返すというコードを書きました。
しかし、
➀のコードだとdbErrorの変数が更新されずにnullのまま返されてしまいます
➁のコードだとreturn文でエラーが出てしまいます

どこを改善すればエラーを返すことができるのでしょうか？

---

①のコード

```
private fun dbCheck(userid:String):String?{
    var dbError:String? = null
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val docRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid)
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document->
            dbError = if(document.exists()){
                "既に利用されているIDです"
            }else {
                null
            }
        }
     return dbError
}
```

②のコード

```
private fun dbCheck(userid:String){
    var dbError:String? = null
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val docRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid)
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document->
            dbError = if(document.exists()){
                "既に利用されているIDです"
            }else {
                null
            }
            return@addOnSuccessListener dbError //ここがエラーになる
        }
}
```

Comment: "2のコードだとエラーが出る" については、実際に表示されたエラーメッセージも質問に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: エラーメッセージがないのでなんともいえませんが、Kotlinで関数から`String?` を返す場合には、[返り値の型の指定が必要です](https://dogwood008.github.io/kotlin-web-site-ja/docs/reference/functions.html#%E6%98%8E%E7%A4%BA%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E6%88%BB%E3%82%8A%E5%80%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%9E%8B)。

Answer (score 0):

`docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener`でaddしているリスナー `{ document -> ...`は非同期で実行されます。
ですので①のコードだと、docRef.get().addOnSuccessListenerを実行した後すぐに`return dbError`が実行されることになるのでnullが返ることになります。

対応策としては、

1. doCheckメソッドがdocumentが正常に取得できた場合、エラーの場合のそれぞれのコールバック関数を引数として受け取るか
2. あるいはcoroutineで非同期処理に対応した実装にする

などがあると思います。

1の場合のサンプルです。

```kotlin
private fun dbCheck(userid:String, onSuccess:()->Unit, onError:() -> Unit) {
    ...
    ...
    if(document.exists()){
        onError()
    }else {
        onSuccess()
    }
    ....
```

（この実装だとメソッド名と実行している内容が噛み合ってないですが・・）

2の非同期処理は少々長くなるので、次の記事等が参考になるかと思います。
https://qiita.com/amay077/items/54deb0de587baae47732

Comment: onError関数とonSuccess関数内はエラーメッセージを設定する処理でよいのでしょうか？

Comment: そこは実装次第ですね。ただそれについては本質問の主旨ではないので、これ以上ここでやり取りしないほうがいいと思いますm(_ _)m